# crop Image in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting an image and I want to remove the whitespace from it. so I have to check the color of every pixel, if the complete row is of white color then crop it. I am not able to get any solution,Please help.

Comment: Take a look on this open source project: https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/Xam.Plugins.ImageCropper

Comment: I can't give the option of cropping image, this is a internal process.

Comment: @Mannu Hi, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture the RGB for each pixel point of the image. When its RGB is equal to white color then modify its alpha to 0 to remove it. I make a method for you referring to:

```
UIImage imageToTransparent(UIImage image)
{
    var imageWidth = (int)image.Size.Width;
    var imageHeight = (int)image.Size.Height;

    var bytesPerRow = imageWidth * 4;
    var rgbImageBuf = new byte[bytesPerRow * imageHeight];

    CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContext context = new CGBitmapContext(rgbImageBuf, imageWidth, imageHeight, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                        CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrder32Little | CGBitmapFlags.NoneSkipLast);

    context.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), image.CGImage);

    int pixelNum = imageWidth * imageHeight * 4;
    var pCurPtr = rgbImageBuf;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelNum; i = i + 4)
    {
        // You can modify this scope to choose which color you want to remove
        if (pCurPtr[i + 1] > 240 && pCurPtr[i + 2] > 240 && pCurPtr[i + 3] > 240)
        {
            pCurPtr[i] = 0;
        }

    }

    CGDataProvider dataProvider = new CGDataProvider(rgbImageBuf);

    CGImage imageRef = new CGImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, 8, 32, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                        CGBitmapFlags.Last | CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrder32Little, dataProvider,
                                        null, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);

    dataProvider.Dispose();

    UIImage resultUIImage = new UIImage(imageRef);

    imageRef.Dispose();
    context.Dispose();
    colorSpace.Dispose();

    return resultUIImage;           
}
```